# Menu getting out of scope

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu centered in the middle of the website, and a transition is applied to in such a way that if one of its elements is clicked, the entire menu move to the ultimate left of the screen in this form / . But the problem is that part of the words in the menu are disappearing when reaching the end left. Any help please?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/yejcbz7p/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="logo" class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<p class="custom-class"><a href="">Go to the main website</a>

</p>
<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul class="headlines">
        <li id="item1">
            <button>Aaaaaaaa</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item2">
            <button>Bbbbbbb</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item3">
            <button>Cccccccc </button>
        </li>
        <li id="item4">
            <button>Ddddddd </button>
        </li>
        <li id="item5">
            <button>Eeeeeeee Eee. </button>
        </li>
        <li id="item6">
            <button>Fffffffff </button>
        </li>
        <li id="item7">
            <button>Ggggggggg </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #222;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 1.3em;
}

.custom-class {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: -130px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

b, strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}

samp {
    display: none;
}

img {
    -webkit-animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    background: transparent;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: none;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    left: 0px;
}

#item7 {
    transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
}

#item6 {
    transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
}

#item5 {
    transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
}

#item4 {
    transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
}

#item3 {
    transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
}

#item2 {
    transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    ;
}

#item1 {
    transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
}

#item1>button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#item2>button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#item3>button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#item4>button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#item5>button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#item6>button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#item7>button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.permahover li {
    opacity: 1;
    left: -46%;
}

.headlines li {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000000;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.headlines:hover li, .headlines.active li {
        /* PARENT HOVER */
    opacity: 0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
        /* Dim all */;
}

.headlines li:hover, .headlines li.active {
        /* SINGLE HOVER */
    opacity: 1;
        /* Max one */
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    };
}

@keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }

    100% {
        filter: grayscale(0%);
    };
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(".menu").on("click", function() {
    $(".menu").addClass('permahover');
});


var $li = $('.headlines li').click(function() {
    var state = !$(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', state);

    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you click function to this:

js:

```
$(".menu").on("click", function () {
    //$(".menu").addClass('permahover');
    var v = 5000;   // just some big number
    $.each($(".menu li"),function(index,obj){
        //alert($(obj).offset().left)
        if(v > $(obj).find("button").offset().left){
            v = $(obj).find("button").offset().left;
        }
    });
    $(".menu li").animate({
        left : "-"+v.toString()
    },500);
});
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yejcbz7p/3/) , this will scrolling according to the content in the list.

Answer (score 0):

In `.permahover li` change the percentage of `left`.

For example, `40%`. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/yejcbz7p/1/

Comment: hey man, its randy they blocked my account for deleting a couple of questions. Thanks it worked

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)

Comment: **But the problem is that part of the words in the menu are disappearing when reaching the end left.**, with your approach the issue is still there, check alignment of `Eeeeeeee Eee.`

Comment: Yes you are correct, sorry for my mistake. But I think it helped him anyways haha. If it didn't, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `left: -46%;` you should just use `text-align: left`.

List item width is 100% of it's parent. if you set `left: -46%` you only change the left-most position of the element (the width will not change). The text will still be centered (based on your css), so the position of the text depends on how much text you got there.